# displaying the PID

Tags: shell-script, shell, variable

I am to write a subscript (called echomyvar) that displays the PID of the process running the script and the value of the variable named myvar. In the text it has:

```
$ cat echomyvar
echo The PID of this process is $$
echo The value of myvar is: $myvar

$ echo $$
2651

$ ./echomyvar
The PID of this process is 4392
The value of myvar is:
```

I was able to create the file echomyvar. So far I have

```
#!/bin/bash
echo  'The PID of this process is $$'
echo  'The Value of myar is: $myvar'
```

I do not know if that is even correct. I am supposed to reproduce what was in the text.

Comment: Is this homework? You need to use double quotes (`"`) for variables to be expanded. `$$` contains the PID of the shell/script itself.

Comment: Use enclosed by double quotes
echo ''The Value of myar is: $myvar''. It will work.

Answer (score 3):

The text that you quote,

```
echo The PID of this process is $$
echo The value of myvar is: $myvar
```

is the literal script that outputs the value of `$$` (the process ID of the shell) and `$myvar`.

It will produce the output

```
The PID of this process is 4392
The value of myvar is:
```

(if the shell's PID happens to be 4392 that is).

It's not an exercise, it's an example, unless you are supposed to produce that *script* as output, but I doubt it.

The `echo` utility outputs each of its arguments to standard output (the terminal in this case). One usually use it like

```
echo 'some string'
```

or

```
echo "some string with a $variable"
```

Using single quotes in the last example would have prevented the shell from expanding `$variable` to its value. Using *no* quotes just means passing multiple arguments to `echo`.

---

For it to be a *good* example, it should have used `printf` (since it's outputting variable data):

```
printf 'The PID of this process is %d\n' "$$"
printf 'The value of myvar is: %s\n' "$myvar"
```

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)